# Connectedness of the Complement of the Countable Union of Closed Jordan Regions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\{V_j\}$ be a countable collection of pairwise disjoint closed Jordan regions in $\mathbb{R}^2$. That is closed sets whose boundary is a Jordan curve.

Let
$$U = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \bigcup V_j \text{.}$$

Is $U$ necessarily connected?

The following example shows that the answer is 'no' if we ask for path connectedness.

Let $\{a_k\} \subset (0,1)$ be a monotonic bi-infinite sequence which accumulates at $0$ and $1$. For $m,n = 0,1,2$, define $V_{k,m,n}$ to be either $[a_{2 k} + m, a_{2 k + 1} + m] \times [n,n+1]$ if $n + m$ is even or $[m,m+1] \times[a_{2 k}+n,a_{2k+1}n]$ if $n + m$ is odd.

There is then no path in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \bigcup V_{k,m,n}$ from any point in $(1,2) \times [1,2]$ to any point in outside $(1,2) \times [1,2]$. However $U$ is still connected here, since any open set containing $(a_{2 k - 1}+1,a_{2k}+1) \times \{1\}$ must intersect some $[1,2] \times (a_{2 l - 1},a_{2 l})$.

Comment: Do you have a question? It seems you are answering to your own question. What are you expecting from people on MSE?

Comment: I've show that the union of the $V_j$ can be connected and that the complement may not be path connected. I'd like to know whether the complement can be disconnected. To put it another way, does there exist a countable collection of pairwise disjoint closed Jordan regions such that the complement of the union is not connected?

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. My mistake.

Comment: I don't understand well what are the $V_j$ in your example. Could you detail a bit more.

Comment: For the non path connectedness I have an other (simpler?) example. Consider a monotonic strictly decreasing sequence $(a_n)$ and a monotonic increasing sequence $(b_n)$ such that $a_n\to 0$ and $b_n\to\infty$. Define $V_j:=[a_{2j+1},a_{2j}]\times[-b_j,b_j]$. There is no path in $U$ going from a point with positive abscissa to a point with negative abscissa. So $U$ is not path connected.

Comment: That definitely works as an easier example. I've edited the question to hopefully make my one clearer.